# implementation of quicksort

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

The following **quicksort** code comes from [programming pearls](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/sort.cpp)

```
void qsort3(int l, int u)
{   int i, j;
    DType t;
    if (l >= u)
        return;
    t = x[l];
    i = l;
    j = u+1;
    for (;;) {
        do i++; while (i <= u && x[i] < t);
        do j--; while (x[j] > t);
        if (i > j)
            break;
        swap(i, j);
    }
    swap(l, j);
    qsort3(l, j-1);
    qsort3(j+1, u);
}
```

In the two-way partitioning part, there is one line:

```
if (i > j)
```

**My question** is can I change this line to:

```
if(i >= j)
```

The reason that I think it's OK to do this is that:
`(i==j)` <=> `(x[i] == t)` so that we don't need to
swap x[i] and x[j]. And we just break out the `for` loop.

The following code of the `for` loop is `swap(l, j)`.
Since x[j] == t == x[l], `swap(l, j)` has nothing to
do with the partition.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't looked at any of the code, but instinctively, some implementations of quicksort are a STABLE sort, meaning the same element order of equal elements will be preserved. Using `if (i >= j )` *might* mess that up. Pure speculation though

Comment: @AK4749: No, quicksort is generally *not* a stable sorting algorithm.

Comment: @digitalvision yep my bad, remembered it incorrectly, efficient versions are not

Comment: @AK4749, The original code(if(x>j)) is not stable, as it swaps two equal items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that, Yes, you can make that change:

swap(i, j) is unrewarding when i == j, and the next iteration after i == j unconditionally increments i and decrements j and will thus cause the loop to terminate with no change to the array anyway.